# Задание и вывод данных в SASM

Tags: sasm

SASM выводит -16898, хотя число в десятичной 150. Как можно правильно задать?

```
%include "io.inc"

section .DATA
    a: dw 10010110


section .text
    global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    ;write your code here
    MOV eax, 0
    MOV ax, word[a]      ; Первый множитель в регистр AL
    
    PRINT_DEC 4, ax
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: Если двухбайтный регистр выводите, то и размер данных нужно указать 2: `PRINT_DEC 2, ax`

Comment: 48638         ```````````````````````````````````````               .

Comment: А под отладчиком что показывает в этом регистре?

Comment: и в `PRINT_DEC 2, ax`  будет -16898

Comment: C:\Users\ююю\AppData\Local\Temp\SASM\program.asm:4: warning: word data exceeds bounds

Comment: А если `a: db 10010110` `MOV al, [a]` `PRINT_DEC 4, eax`?

Comment: наверное нужно писать для перевода. так 254 выводит

Comment: Ну он просто не принимает двоичное представление

Comment: А, ну так это не двоичное представление, несмотря на то что вы там 0 и 1 только используете, это десятичное число 10010110. В [доках nasm](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html) я не вижу, чтобы была поддержка литералов в двоичном виде, так что переводите в шестнадцатеричный вид, будет 0x96